# Error installing Ruby with RVM (fails installing RubyGems)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 via RVM.  However, when it gets to the point of installing RubyGems, I get this:

> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 The requested url
>   does not exist:
>   'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-.tgz' Trying
>   ftp:// URL instead.
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time 
>   Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:00
>   --:--:--     0curl: (28) connect() timed out!
>
> There was an error, please check
>   /home/jjw0c4/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/*.log

There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.
Halting the installation.

My guess is the URL "`/rubygems-.tgz`", shouldn't there be a version number on the end?

Answer (score 17):

This was a bug in the earlier version of RVM.

Update RVM:

```
rvm get stable # OR:
rvm get head   # OR if none worked:
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

The installer also does update (in fact latest `rvm get ...` just calls the installer)

Comment: This is the version that I have installed now: rvm 1.11.6 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/].  I tried both rvm get stable and rvm get head, and both just say "RVM reloaded!"

Comment: I am using the latest version (1.14.1 at writing) and still have this bug.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up removing and then reinstalling RVM using the command on the RVM site:

`curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Now I have

`rvm 1.12.1 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

installed.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no need to remove RVM, running the installer is perfectly safe and will update your installation of RVM

Comment: @mpapis Good to know. I haven't seen that mentioned on the RVM site. It would be nice to add.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the same reason you are having a problem or not, but for me, I think the reason I was having this problem was because my cURL CA bundle (the list of valid certificate authorities) was outdated. So I think it was failing on validating SSL certificates. When I updated my CS bundle it was able to install RubyGems just fine.

- [How to update cURL CA bundle on RedHat](https://serverfault.com/questions/394815/how-to-update-curl-ca-bundle-on-redhat)
- [How to update cURL CA bundle on Ubuntu 10.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/151157/ubuntu-10-04-curl-how-do-i-fix-update-the-ca-bundle)

**Update:** I also found out that some RubyGems.org servers were down when I was in the process of installing RubyGems so that is why it was resulting in 404 errors. I tried again today, and it worked.